# Proving the form of a sequence's terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

How do I go about attacking this problem and what is it asking?

Suppose that $\alpha^2 = \alpha + 1$ and suppose $F_n$ denotes the Fibonacci sequence.

Show that $\alpha^3 = 2\alpha +1, \alpha^4 = 3\alpha +2$

Comment: "suppose $F_n$ denotes the Fibonacci sequence" is somewhat pointless to write when the problem does not mention the numbers $F_n$ at all. It is of course related though, since $x^2=x+1$ is the characteristic equation of the recursion defining the Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Have you tried multiplying both sides of $x^2=x+1$ by $x$? Do it!

Comment: So the F_n part of the problem is just trying to throw me off?

Comment: Antonio, Anon's second comment above is all you need to know.

Comment: Ok, so what is the problem asking though, so I understand what I'm looking for. Thanks. That's the part I'm not really sure of. And if i multiplied both sides by x, I'll get x^3 = x^2 + x. So where does that fit into this problem?

Comment: For what it's worth, $x^2=x+1$ is true if and only iff $x^2-x-1=0$. If you write each of your equations in the form $f(x)=0$, take a look at the graphs of the functions $f(x)$ you end up with. http://i.imgur.com/BW7Ht1q.png

Comment: If you figure out how to show that $\alpha^3=2\alpha+1$ and $\alpha^4=3\alpha+2$, you should be able to see that for each positive integer $n$ there will be some constants $c_n$ and $d_n$ such that $\alpha^n=c_n\alpha+d_n$. Calculate a few more powers of $\alpha$ and take a good look at those constants, and you’ll see why the Fibonacci numbers were mentioned.

Comment: You say "I'll get $x^3=x^2+x$. So where does that fit into this problem?" Let's ponder this for a moment. You got $x^2+x$ but you need $2x+1$. Somehow you need to show that $x^2+x=2x+1$. Or in other words, $x^2=x+1$... but wait, you already know this, because it was given! And so this part of the problem is done, and that is all it took. I encourage you to sit and ponder like this as much as you can. Not pondering won't help! Much of mathematics is learned experimentally: even if you don't know what to do, at least do *something*, and then *keep* doing things until stuff occurs to you.

Answer (score 1):

More explicitly,
since
$x^2 = x+1$,
$x^3 = x(x^2)
=x(x+1)
=x^2+x
=(x+1)+x
=2x+1
$.

Do the same for
$x^4$.

Essentially,
any power of $x$,
say $x^n$ with $n \ge 3$,
can be replaced
by lower powers of $x$
via
$x^n
=x^{n-2}x^2
=x^{n-2}(x+1)
=x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}
$.

Keep on applying this
until only linear and constant terms are left.

You will find an interesting formula
for $x^n$
in terms of $x$ and $1$.